# Passing Data From One Collection View to an Embedded Collection View

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `mainUICollectionView` with a custom `mainUICollectionViewCell`. In this `mainUICollectionViewCell` is a `nestedUICollectionView` with a `nestedUILabel` and a `nestedUICollectionViewCell`.

The data that I am attempting to load is a variable called `questions = [Question]()`, where `Question` is a custom class. Each `Question` object has a `title` and a `[string]()`.

Here is what is the logic I am trying to implement:
1.`mainCollectionView`should populate based on the `questions.count`
2. `nestedLabel.text = question[indexPath.row].tite`
3. `nestedCollectionView` should populate based on the `answer` property of the respective `question`.

I have done the first two tasks with ease by referencing the `viewControllers` `questions` property. However, since the `UICollectionViewDelegate` and `UICollectionViewDataSource` for my `nestedCollectionView`are in the `mainUICollectionViewCell`, I am unable to get a reference for it. How might I achieve this third step?

Thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
class ViewController : UIViewController {

   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
  cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

   // pass data only ,this in the  viewController
        let answers = questions[indexPath.row].answers
        cell.answers = answers 


   //

   }

}
```

&

```
class mainUICollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell , UICollectionViewDelegate , UICollectionViewDataSource {

       var answers = [String]()

       override func awakeFromNib () {

        super.awakeFromNib()

        self.nestedCollectionView.delegate = self

        self.nestedCollectionView.dataSource= self

       // register the nib / nestedUICollectionViewCell here 

       }
}
```

//

Inside `cellForRow` in the `ASKpScoreLog` before `return cell` do

```
cell.collectionView.reloadData()
```

Comment: Thankyou for your response. Do I implement this in my `mainCollectionViewCell` or in the `viewController`? And by `innerCollectionView` you mean `nestedCollectionView`, correct?

Comment: Hello, thank you for editing your answer. I am still having trouble understanding it, however. Coul you try writing it in a different way?

Comment: Implement code inside **mainUICollectionViewCell** as if that nestedCollectionView is in **ViewController**

Comment: The code is not working. Passing the data worked, but only for the first index and the rest were based on the first index. When implemeting the collectionView.register method, the code crashed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170191/discussion-between-m-i-and-sh-khan).